# simple javascript example not working

Tags: javascript

I am learning javascript and i can't manage to make this work, an alert message should appear when i click the submit button

Html

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Understanding the Document Object Model</title>
    <script type="javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 id="title">Understanding the Document Object Model</h1>
    <p id="first">This is the first paragraph</p>
    <p id="second"><strong>This is the second paragraph</strong></p>
    <p id="third">Third paragraph</p>
    <input type="submit" id="clickMe" value="Click Me"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript script.js

```
window.onload=function(){
document.getElementById("clickMe").onclick=runTheExample;
}

function runTheExample(){
alert("running the example");
}
```

Comment: Submit buttons are supposed to be in a form. If it's just a button, then use a type button `<input type="button" ...>` or a button element: `<button ...>...</button>`.

Comment: Your code seems to work just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/jmLr5fyz/

Comment: I also think it works ok https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MarZdO

Comment: @Saravana: which browsers would that be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `type` attribute is wrong.
It should be `"text/javascript"`

It works fine for me after making that change

==================================

EDIT:

As a note, my debugging process was to try invoking the alert() directly in the script. `script.js` became:

```
alert("running the example");

window.onload=function(){
    document.getElementById("clickMe").onclick=runTheExample;
}

function runTheExample(){
    alert("running the example");
}
```

That was triggering the alert either, which says that the whole script isn't in play. So it must be the invocation of the script that's the problem.
Once you've determined that, there aren't many things left to check.

Comment: Good catch. However, it would be even better to remove it completely. (Maybe you should also say which `type` attrribute)

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

You change your external javascript file link like this. Because,type attribute of script tag should come as text/javascript